# Algorithm for textual context matching in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, npm

I have to implement an algorithm as a Node.js app where I'll be getting to strings and based on their context I'll have to decide if its a match or not. Take a taxi service for example. A person asking for a taxi can be considered string one. A taxi driver willing to offer his service could be considered string2. The algorithm should process these two strings and for this case return a match. I have lot of test data to train my algorithm on, if need be.

So far I have come across [Bayes Document Classification algorithm](http://burakkanber.com/blog/machine-learning-naive-bayes-1/) and I think it could get the job done.

I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, or any existing npm module that I could use?

Example strings:

S1 : I am looking for apartments in new york
S2 : Our website lists apartments for sale in new york.
Outcome : Match.

S1 : I am looking for restaurants in new york
S2 : John sells computers.
Outcome : No Match.

Comment: Can you give an example of string1 and string2?  Also, what does your data set look like, how is it formatted, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which will give you a number of corrections to make so that to strings match, you can convert it to percentages, to [approximate the match](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927) is the JavaScript implementation and can be used as nodejs module.